# How to access to ADDRESS.LIST node?

Tags: php, json, xml-parsing, extract

I want to get `ADDRESS.LIST` XML node value. My sample XML is as:

```
$result = "<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <STATUS>1</STATUS>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
    <DESC></DESC>
    <DATA>
        <MESSAGE xmlns:UDF=\"TallyUDF\">
            <ADDRESS.LIST TYPE=\"String\">
                <ADDRESS>address text</ADDRESS>
                <ADDRESS>address text</ADDRESS>
                <ADDRESS>address text</ADDRESS>
                <ADDRESS>address text</ADDRESS>
            </ADDRESS.LIST>
        </MESSAGE>
    </DATA>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>";
```

I am trying using PHP as:

```
$repaired = str_replace("&#4; ", "", $result);
$array_data = simplexml_load_string($repaired, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOERROR);

$address    = [];

$status = (string) $array_data->HEADER->STATUS;

if (strpos($status, '1') !== false) {

    $i = 0; 
    $address = array();
    foreach ($array_data->BODY->DATA->MESSAGE->'ADDRESS.LIST' as $item):

        $address[$i]['ADDRESS']     = (string) $item->ADDRESS;

        $i++;
    endforeach; 

    $response["status"] = $status;
    $response["data"]['address']  = $address;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

but it shows:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''ADDRESS.LIST'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE)"  error

How to get the `<ADDRESS.LIST>` value properly?

Comment: use curly braces `{'blah-blah.di.blah'}` to access the properties such as that

Comment: I changed the title to explain what you want to get, indented XML for better reading, uses `>` to format error messages and removed some useless texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store value variable then use or you can use this by `{}`

option 1:

```
$address_list = "ADDRESS.LIST";
foreach($array_data->BODY->DATA->MESSAGE->$address_list as $item):
```

option 2:

```
foreach($array_data->BODY->DATA->MESSAGE->{'ADDRESS.LIST'} as $item):
```